# How would I calculate the heat produced by a child?

Tags: metabolism, heat, children-kids

Odd question I know, but I'm looking into stroller covers and I was thinking about how to simulate the heat a child would generate inside one (ignore outside sources like solar loading for the moment). I didn't find any research on it, only vague estimates that an adult human creates about 100 Watts. I wasn't sure where that number came from but the daily calorie recommendation for an adult male is around 3000 calories. And if you convert that to Watt/hrs you get 3000 * 0.001162 or 3.486W/hr.  At 24hours that's 83.6 Watts which is close enough that I could see people starting to quote the human output as 100 Watts.

So for a stroller age child who has a caloric intake of more like 1400-2000 cal depending on age that gives me 1.6W/hr to 2.3W/hr. I'm thinking of emulating this with a little heater or perhaps a light bulb. Do my numbers sound reasonable or am I thinking about this wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: A major issue with your calculation is that a *food Calorie* (capital letter) is 1000 calories - a weird convention. Another thing is that a Watt is a measure of the rate of energy conversion - i.e. a Joule per second. A Joule per second per hour makes no sense. Easier to start by working in Joules in the first place as they're the SI unit of energy.

Comment: Thank you, two good points.

Comment: Also consider that not all energy ingested is lost as heat. Particularly during early childhood, a not insignificant proportion of Calories are used to build muscle and organ mass.

Comment: @IanCampbell interesting. So what happens to the energy input then? It it stored as chemical energy in those organs and muscles?

Comment: Partially. Some of the chemical energy is used to form high energy bonds in molecules necessary for new cellular structures. Other ingested molecules which contain chemical energy are used for cellular structures directly. This would be in place of being broken down to create energy storage molecules that power cellular functions or are directly used to generate heat. See [Thermogenesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermogenesis)